# php Change Text on 26th day of each month

Tags: php

I need to change the heading over a repeating countdown timer, which goes off at midnight local time, every month, on the 26th day.  I've looked at many solutions and I just can't find anything that would do something like this:

```
if (26th day of month through end of month) {
    echo "<h1>Good Until End of Month</h1>";
} else {
    echo "<h1>Will begin in...</h1>";
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the PHP date functions/manual? http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php `d Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros` seems like it'd work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

if (date("d") >= 26) {
   echo "<h1>Good Until End of Month</h1>";
} else {
    echo "<h1>Will begin in...</h1>";
}
```

There you have it, using the `date()` function

Comment: It's really that simple?  I've looked at all these complicated date/time snippets and I should have thought simple!  Thank you.

Comment: Could you please classify the answer as correct? Thanks

Comment: He said day 26, it does what he want

Comment: Actually, what I wanted was from the 26th to the end of month.  So the correct answer is:

    if (date("d") >= 26)

Answer (score 0):

Since you've written the text "Good Until End of Month", I'm assuming you need the text from 26th to the end of the month. To check if your date lies between the 26th and end of the month, your condition should be like

```
if (date("d") >= 26 && date("d") <= 31) {
   echo "<h1>Good Until End of Month</h1>";
} else {
    echo "<h1>Will begin in...</h1>";
}
```

Comment: Checking the day to be less than or equal to 31 is a wasted condition.